# Margins vs. positions in fixed position elements

Tags: css

A little popup told me I had a new Twitter follower in my browser. I clicked inspect element to poke around, and of course wasn't surprised that it was a fixed position element, but the CSS surprised me.

```
#spoonbill-outer {
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
margin: 22px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Is there a reason for using margins instead of `right:22px`, `bottom:22px`?

Comment: It is because margin would not position the element as intended. To position a fixed element, you must use either the right, left, top and/or bottom properties.

Comment: @unheilig but twitter is using margins, not right left top bottom properties.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting point to consider, I tried it both ways and essentially both approaches lead to the same result.

I would say both approaches are equivalent in the simplest example.

If you look at the CSS specification, the left/right offsets and the left/right margins and the width can be constrained depending on which values are specified or set to auto.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

However, I found it hard to imagine a case in which specifying offsets versus margins would make a difference (there might be an exotic case, but I can't think of it off the top of my head).

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.popup {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 40px;
}
.popup-alt {
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">Yellow Popup Element</div>
<div class="popup-alt">Blue Popup Element</div>
```